# how to add several activemq NetworkConnectors in spring boot with java config, not configued with XML file

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, broker

usually, we add NetworkConnectors configuration in activemq.xml before we start the activemq service as below:

```
<networkConnectors>
      <networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://localhost:62001)"/>
 </networkConnectors>
```

but this time, i just used spring boot with activemq embeded. and i want to configure more networkConnectors danymiclly when the mq running. so i could not choose to add these in activemq.xml. but need to configure with java code in spring boot. i don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

you define the broker bean and add what you want as you do in xml

```
@Bean
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:5671");
    broker.addNetworkConnector("static:(tcp://localhost:62001)");
    return broker;
}
```

Comment: thank you.i have another question. if i still need to download activemq package from activeMQ website and unzip and click activemq.bat to run it after i imported spring-boot-starter-activemq dependency. i found when i create a BrokerService with java code not in xml. and also run  activemq.bat, i report error and service can not up. But when i stop and close activemq.bat,it work well. so i wondered when i imported spring-boot-starter-activemq dependency, i no need to download activeMQ zip package from website and install on my computer again

Comment: nope, with bean broker() you create a full embedded AMQ broker, not need external one